# C++ PyObject Python-Type detect/check?

Tags: python, c++

How can I detect / check the Python-Type of a PyObject?
`PyObject_HasAttrString` can be used to check, but how do I get the AttrString of a given `PyObject`?

```
int modify(cv::cuda::GpuMat* cVal, py::object &pobj)
  {
    py::handle ptype = pobj.get_type(); //?? ...
    PyObject *pobject = pobj.ptr();
    auto typeCheck = PyObject_HasAttrString(pobject, "cv2.cuda_GpuMat"); //?? 
    if (!typeCheck) 
      return(0);
    PyObject *pobject1 = PyObject_GetAttrString( pobject, "cv2.cuda_GpuMat");
    cv::cuda::GpuMat *pyVal = (cv::cuda::GpuMat *)PyLong_AsVoidPtr(pobject1);
    // *pyVal = *cVal; // kidding
    return(1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you know what type it should be so you can check if you can convert to that type, for example: [PyTuple_Check](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_Check), [PyUnicode_Check](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#unicode-type), etc.

Assuming you are using numpy arrays, I would look at [PyArray_FROM_OTF](http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/numpy/user/c-info.how-to-extend.html#PyArray_FROM_OTF) which will return an ndarray from any Python object that can be converted into an array:

```cpp
    PyArrayObject* pPyArrayA = reinterpret_cast<PyArrayObject*>(PyArray_FROM_OTF(pPyA, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_ARRAY_IN_ARRAY));
    if(pPyArrayA == nullptr)
    {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Failed to convert a to nd array.");
        return nullptr;
    }

    size_t iSizeA = static_cast<size_t>(PyArray_SIZE(pPyArrayA));
    const double* pcdA = static_cast<const double*>(PyArray_DATA(pPyArrayA));
```